# simple WebKitGTK application does not show frame at runtime (debian/WSL)

Tags: c, debian, gtk, webkit, wsl-2

I am trying to build a simple WebKit example. After first trying to use an older version, I am stuck upgrading to webkitgtk-6.0.

My code is as following:

```
// cc `pkg-config --cflags --libs webkitgtk-6.0 ` WebKitTest2.c 
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <webkit/webkit.h>

void
activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer)
{
  GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "NPC");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 800, 600);

  GtkWidget *webView = webkit_web_view_new ();

  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), webView);
  webkit_web_view_load_uri (WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW (webView),
                            "https:/google.com");

  gtk_widget_show(window);
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status;

    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new ("com.example.GtkApplication",
                                G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);
    
    return status;
}
```

results in:

```
$ ./WebKitTest 

    
libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open vgem: /usr/lib/dri/vgem_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
    
    libEGL warning: failed to open /dev/dri/card0: Permission denied
    
    
    (process:2): Gdk-WARNING **: 14:30:13.944: Settings portal not found: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
    libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open vgem: /usr/lib/dri/vgem_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
    
    libEGL warning: failed to open /dev/dri/card0: Permission denied
    
    ^C
```

Any ideas? I am using debian WSL. No window pops up, but I do see a taskbar icon. If I click on that icon, nothing happens.

This was the older sample that worked fine:

```
//clang `pkg-config --cflags --libs webkit2gtk-4.1` WebKitTest.c++

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <webkit2/webkit2.h>

static void
destroyWindowCb (GtkWidget *widget, GtkWidget *window)
{
  gtk_main_quit ();
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *main_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (main_window), 800, 600);

  WebKitWebView *webView = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW (webkit_web_view_new ());
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (main_window), GTK_WIDGET (webView));

  g_signal_connect (main_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroyWindowCb),
                    NULL);

  webkit_web_view_load_uri (webView, "https://google.us");

  gtk_widget_show_all (main_window);

  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I also tried that under Ubuntu WSL, same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out the problem ceases to exist when using a real virtual machine and not WSL :)